# Entrada e saída no Visual Basic do Arena

Tags: visual-basic-6

Estou tendo problema com entrada e saída de dados entre a simulação do Arena Rockwell software e o Visual Basic nativo deles mesmo. Basicamente o que quero é receber dados da simulação para o Visual Basic, processá-los e devolver o resultado para a simulação. Comecei com algo bem simples, estou tentando fazer com que a variável "Destino" seja sempre 5, mas usando VBA, então toda vez que uma entidade entrar no bloco VBA, esta variável deve ser setada para 5, depois passar pelo bloco de decisão e ir para o "Dispose 5", como demonstrado na imagem em anexo.

Eu escrevi esse código

```
Option Explicit

Dim m As Arena.Model

Dim S As Arena.SIMAN

Private Sub ModelLogic_RunBeginSimulation()

    Set m = ThisDocument.Model

    Set S = m.SIMAN

End Sub

Private Sub VBA_Block_1_Fire()

    Dim Destino As Integer

    S.VariableArrayValue(S.SymbolNumber("Destino")) = 5

End Sub
```

Mas na linha `S.VariableArrayValue(S.SymbolNumber("Destino")) = 5` aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:
"Run-time error '91':
Object variable or with block variable not set"
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode adicionar o código completo? Verifique se está sendo chamado o método `ModelLogic_RunBeginSimulation` antes do `VBA_Block_1_Fire`.

Comment: Este já é o código completo, creio que o Arena já se encarrega de chamar as rotinas na ordem correta.
Outra coisa, "Destino" é a variável que controla o bloco decide, não tinha deixado isso claro quando fiz a pergunta.

Comment: Pela mensagem de erro parece que `S` não foi criado, ou seja, recebeu um `new`. Adicione um Breakpoint execute o código passo a passo e veja se `S` não é `Is Nothing`.

Comment: Coloquei alguns IF's e constatei que o S não é Is Nothing

Answer (score 0):

Com ajuda do cara do canal chamado "Fayad" consegui encontrar uma solução, entretanto usando outras funções, e o código ficou assim:

```
Option Explicit

Dim m As Arena.Model

Dim s As Arena.SIMAN

Private Sub ModelLogic_RunBeginSimulation()

Set m = ThisDocument.Model

Set s = m.SIMAN

End Sub

Private Sub VBA_Block_1_Fire()

Dim s As SIMAN
Set s = ThisDocument.Model.SIMAN


s.EntityAttribute(s.ActiveEntity, s.SymbolNumber("Destino")) = 5
End Sub
```